# Why use add_library({tgt} IMPORTED) versus target_link_libraries( -l {.so | .a})?

Tags: cmake, libraries, build-system

What is the purpose of using the statement:

```
add_library(<tgt> [SHARED|STATIC] IMPORTED)
```

From what I have found even if you create an imported library target above you still would need to specify the specific location of the actual .so or .a. This would take at least 3 cmake commands to link to an executable and the compiler still would not automatically search through the common include directories on your OS.

Example:
[cmake code to link IMPORTED lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648375/what-are-the-differences-between-imported-target-and-interface-libraries)

From the CMake documentation I understand there are really 3 ways to link a library that is not built as a target in a subproject of your overall application/library.

[CMake target_link_libraries() documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/target_link_libraries.html#id2)

1. Using a CMake package for one of the shipped package scripts.
2. Using a linker flag:

   ```
   target_link_libraries(<tgt> [SHARED|STATIC|...] -lncursesw)
   ```
3. Or using the IMPORTED library method (showcased in code at top).

A major difference when using the second method is that it only takes a single line of code and will search through all of your compiler's predefined include directories on you OS. Could anyone help me understand why the add_library() method is used?

---

Additional Realated SO Posts:

[Include directories for IMPORTED libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355884/include-directories-for-imported-library?rq=1)

[CMake imported library behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850736/cmake-imported-library-behaviour?rq=1)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use `add_library(<tgt> [SHARED|STATIC] IMPORTED)` whenever you need to set properties such as dependencies, compile definitions, compile flags  etc for `<tgt>`, and/or by extension, any targets that are linking against `<tgt>`.

Let's say you have two static libraries; `libfoobar.a` and `libraboof.a`, where `libfoobar.a` requires `libraboof.a`. Let's also say that these libraries contain some features that are enabled by `-DSOME_FEATURE`.

```
add_library(raboof STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(raboof PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION <path-to-libraboof.a>
    INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "SOME_FEATURE"
)

add_library(foobar STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(foobar PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION <path-to-libfoobar.a>
    INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES raboof
)
```

So when you link against `libfoobar.a`:

```
add_executable(my_app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_app foobar)
```

`CMake` will make sure to link all dependencies in the correct order and will in this case also append `-DSOME_FEATURE` to the compile flags when you build `my_app`. Note that since we added `libraboof.a` as a dependency to `libfoobar.a`, `-DSOME_FEATURE` is added to any target that link against `libfoobar.a` through the transitive property.

If you don't use `add_library(<tgt> <SHARED|STATIC> IMPORTED)` in a scenario like this, you would have to manage any dependencies and required build options yourself for each target, which is quite error-prone.

This method is also often used in `Config`-modules for multi-component libraries to manage dependencies between the components.

Comment: I can't understand you answer very clearly, can you give a example with real code?